# Code Blocks "It seems like project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?"

Tags: c++, build, compilation, codeblocks

Code blocks bee working fine for me.  But yesterday whenever I try to compile a small program a window appears showing

> It seems like project has not been built yet.
>   Do you wan to build it now?

I also found similar  questions but in all of them not a single program is working. But  in mine "hello world!" program and some other programs are working.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int b[], int s);

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    print(a, 5);
}

void print(int b[] , int s){

    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){

        cout << b[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

[image]

I installed code blocks in another computer and it's working fine.

[image]

I'm still learning C++.

Comment: So... what if you just click yes?

Comment: Nothing appears, widow just closes.

Comment: Probably your program just prints the number and closes.

Try adding `cout << "Press Enter to Continue";`
`cin.ignore(); `

to the end of your program (after print but before return 0).

This will make the program wait for you to press something before closing.

Answer (score 2):

What if I tell you that you should **build**  your program to run it?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) says:

> In the field of computer software, the term software **build** refers
>   either to the process of converting source code files into standalone
>   software artifact(s) that can be run on a computer, or the result of
>   doing so. One of the most important steps of a software build is the
>   **compilation process** where source code files are converted into executable code.

It may be possible that your compiler is not linked properly to C::B or many other errors will be shown after you try to build your project, but for now (unless you post any build log) - you have to **build your application in order to run** it.

Comment: If I run the Hello world program it runs without any error.Also if I change the array size from a[5] to a[3] same program works fine

Comment: @Athul, so what's the problem? Does your program compile and run?

Comment: NO it isn't running. Every time i try to build and run , this dialogue box appears and it returns to the program for both Yes and No.
It runs on my other pc. Why isn't it running for a[5]????

Comment: Does any log appear?

Comment: Nop, I'm not at home now. I can check again when I get home

Comment: Add `return 0;` at the end of your *not working* program and reply.

Answer (score 2):

Solved , Anti-virus was deleting the .exe file for some reason. I put the project file folder in the "exclusion list" of anti-virus (or you can deactivate the anti-virus)

Answer (score 1):

In CodeBlocks when a program is part of a project, it needs to built so that the compiler puts together all of the individual parts of the project.
If you do not want it, just make it a stand-alone program by opening it out of the project.
Pressing F9 would do just fine.

Comment: I compiled the program(using build and run button-one with a gear and play button). It works fine in my other computer.

Answer (score 1):

**This happens if you add a New File to the project and try to build-run the code.**

The solution is to create a new file outside the project and then right-click on the tab (where the name of the file writes, followed by .cpp) and select `Add file to active project`. In the pop-up GUI, check the `Debug` and `Release` options and hit OK. Now if you build and run, you will no longer have the message saying `“It seems like project has not been built yet. Do you wan to build it now?”`.